# What do M, D and L5 mean at the end of a line in an Amadeus Itinerary Element description?

Tags: terminology, gds

In amadeus system when adding an itinerary element I get the following response:

```
EK 530 B 21JAN 1*DXBCOK DK1  0245 0805  21JAN  E  0 772 M
9W 312 T 30NOV 7 DELBOM DK4  2100 2305  30NOV  E  0 73H D

SR 192 C 15MAY 1 ZRHBOM HK1     A  1210 2355   M11   0 L5
QF 141 Y 19MAY 1 BNEAKL HK1     I  0645 0810   763   0 B
```

I understand all the tokens in the above response(for first two lines):

- airline
- flight #
- class
- dep date
- day of week
- sector
- status
- dep time
- arrival time
- arrival date
- ticket type
- # stops
- equipment

Except the last characters M on first line and D on the second line and L5 on the third. What do they stand for?

Also on the last two lines what does A and I mean, i.e the letters mentioned after the status HK1. (edit: Got the answer, these are terminals.)

Comment: Thank you @kate gregory for the edit and making my question more explicit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the final column is the *meal code*, which according to the [Amadeus Training Manual](http://www.amadeus.com/web/binaries/1332970199128/blobheader=application/pdf&blobheadername1=Content-Disposition&blobheadervalue1=attachment;+filename=Training_Manual_1A_PK.pdf) (Pakistani version) should be one of the following:

- B Breakfast
- K Continental Breakfast
- L Lunch
- D Dinner
- S Snack
- O Cold Meal
- H Hot Meal
- M Meal (non-specific)
- R Refreshment
- C Alcoholic Beverages, Complimentary
- F Food for Purchase
- P Alcoholic Beverages, for Purchase
- Y Duty Free Sales Available

Comment: thank you for your response. I had another question, in the following what does the last token '0950' signify

SU 232  K  14DEC  SVO F DEL 3  2010  0345+1 E0/333  0950

I know it is time, but time for what?

Comment: Late breakfast? Brunch perhaps?

Comment: My guess would be flight time, but I checked SU 232 and it is only scheduled for six hours.